# Find the id and text of the clicked <li> tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some list tag in my HTML page .I want to find the text and id of list tag separately. Since my list is created in the run time so I cant figure out how to get the id and text value.

I have tried this

```
$("#users li").click(function(e) 
{ 
     console.log($(this).text());
     console.log($(this).id);
});
```

But it is not triggering any click event.

HTML part

```
<div class="card card-body bg-light">
    <h3>Online Users</h3>
    <ul class="list-group" id="users"></ul>
</div>
```

jquery part

```
$(function () {
    var socket =io.connect();
    var $users =$('#users');

    socket.on('get users',function(data){
    var html='';
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
         html+='<li class="list-group-item" id="'+i+'">'+data[i]+'</li>';
    }
    $users.html(html);
    });

    $($users).click(function(e) 
   { 
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).id);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `$users.on("click",".list-group-item",function(...){
....
});`

Edit:

`$users.on("click",".list-group-item",function(e){ 
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log(e.target.id); 
});`

@Dipto Roy

Comment: You can get the correct quotes by holding and sliding on an iPhone

Comment: Thank! I don’t know why I am trying to post from iPhone... my mistake

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone

Comment: You also missed a dot in the class name AND wrapped $(users) unnecessarily ;)

Comment: I have tried this.I can get the text of the list. But cant get the id. It is printing undefined.

Comment: ```$users.on("click",".list-group-item",function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log(e.target.id);
   });```

Comment: please edit the answer to this. @Veselin

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$(document).on('click','#users li',function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Actually since `$('#users')` is likely static, it is closer to the event target to do `$('#users').on('click','li',function(){` or `$users.on('click','li',function(){`

Comment: I have tried this. I can print the text of list tag. But the printing of id is giving undefined.

Comment: try with     
consoel.log($(this).attr('id'));
check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
   $("#users li").click(function(e) 
   { 
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log(this.id);
   });
```

Comment: No he cannot. That is not delegation. Please read the dupe